# Can not configure knockout-validation for messageTemplate

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Knockout validation prints the error messages in black color.
But I want it in my style. And in my application, I want all validation messages
should be in same style. For this I am trying  to configure `knockout-validation` using
the following template and command.

When I bind my viewmodel, I am getting the error message that I put below. What is my mistake? What/ what step am I missing?

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/html" id="errMsg">
    <span class="alert-danger"
          data-bind="if: field.isModified() && !field.isValid(),
                     text: field.error, 
                     attr: { title: field.error }">*</span>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.validation.init({ messageTemplate: 'errMsg' });
</script>
```

I get the following message.

> Message: Multiple bindings (if and text) are trying to control descendant 
>   bindings of the same element. You cannot use these bindings together on the 
>   same element.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own Css for the validation message, just set the `errorMessageClass` config property.

```
ko.validation.init( { errorMessageClass: "yourCssClass" } );
```

Check the doc [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration)

As per your error, you can avoid it by replacing the `if` binding with a `visible` binding:

```
<script type="text/html" id="errMsg">
    <span class="alert-danger"
          data-bind="visible: field.isModified() && !field.isValid(),
                     text: field.error, 
                     attr: { title: field.error }">*</span>
</script>
```